# traversing based on path weights and node properties dijkstra

Tags: neo4j, traversal, dijkstra

Can a least cost path between nodes A and B be found with also checking for some properties on the nodes?

For example, I want to find the shortest bus route from A to B with weight of the links being the distance. So the path should not only be least cost but also the nodes on the path should have a bus station / stop.

So the path returned be least cost path with all nodes as bus stops (say a property bus_stop=yes) .

The TraversalDescription provides evaluator where the node properties can be checked. Is similar possible with Dijkstra ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Neo4j's [`graphalgo`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/package-frame.html) package, you need to supply a custom [`CostEvaluator`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/CostEvaluator.html) to the Dijkstra algorithm. Instead of just using the travel time (aka the relationship property) you should return the sum of travel time (relationship property) plus waiting time at the bus stop (node property):

```
 class BusCostEvaluator implements CostEvaluator<Float> {

     public Float getCost(Relationship r, Direction d) {
         return (Float)r.getStartNode().getProperty("waitTime", 0f) +
             (Float)r.getProperty("travelTime", 0f)
     }

 }
```

Comment: I need to be able to take some decision like exclude and prune on the basis if the node in this path has or not a property. like the start node should have property waitTime less than 20 minutes to be included in the path.
I can iterate the paths after retrieval to check each node in that path for the property and accept or reject the path.
But is it possible to let the algo know which nodes to include while using Dijkstra

Comment: dijekstra also requires that you supply a `PathExpander`, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpander.html. The pathExpander allows you to exclude relationships by not returning them in the `expand` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. It assumes all links have a property weight and sums the path weights and length combination to order the result. It firstly filters only those paths where all nodes have bus_stop as yes

```
MATCH p=a-[r*]->b
WHERE all(x1 in nodes(p) where x1.bus_stop = 'yes')
WITH extract(link IN r| link.weight) AS wts, length(p) AS len
RETURN wts, reduce(sum=0, x IN wts| sum+x) AS totalwt, len
order by totalwt
```